# Не обновляется автоматически код в мобильной версии

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Честно говоря, думаю что пишу не в эту тему, но может кто сталкивался.

Проблема такова, захожу в инспектор кода и включаю мобильную версию своего сайта и пишу изменения в файле(html или css), но изменения не применяются автоматически(использую live server, но не суть) решаю обновиться страницу самостоятельно на что мне Chrome отвечает, что "Нет подключение к интернету" хотя интернет есть и все работает и все данные применяются только тогда когда закрою вкладку и нажму сочетания клавиш Ctrl+Shift+T, ну вообщем открою страницу занова.
Решаю проверить проблему на любом другом сайте, например VK делаю все такие же действия и опять при обновление страницы "Нет подключение к интернету"

Comment: Live server -  расширение браузера?

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы. Открыть DevTools перейти во вкладку Network и как на скриншоте [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODQMm.png) перевести значение из offline в no throttling.